# Trying to keybind spacebar to a mouse button on Ubuntu with no luck

Tags: mouse, ubuntu-18.04, xinput

I've tried xInput and AutoKey, but xInput only seems to allow me to bind mouse buttons to mouse buttons or keyboard buttons to keyboard buttons. For example, I managed to bind my middle mouse button the the "browser back" button on my mouse.

I'm now trying to bind my "browser forward" button to space, with no luck.

With xInput, I tried setting it to 65, which was the code my keyboard sends when I hit the space bar. The command executes with no error, but clicking the button now has no effect whatsoever.

With AutoKey, the issue is with getting my mouse to trigger the script. I have the script set to keyboard.send_keys(" "), but the hotkeys only accept keyboard input...

I've searched for answers to this, but it appears nobody else is attempting to map keyboard keys to the mouse.

Comment: see [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/9754/6936), might be helpful in case you don't find other solution.

Comment: so on Windows, Autohotkey can do this easily. but if you're on Linux - I am not sure, but it might happen that it is not easily achievable.